# padding zero on floating point bash printf

Tags: bash, printf, precision

I would like to have a floating point number printed in bash with padded zeroes to fill a range %5.3f.
I know of printf function.

My problem is the following:

```
printf "0%5.3f\n" 3.00
```

returns, as expected,

```
03.000
```

but the line

```
printf "0%5.3f\n" 23.00
```

gives instead

```
023.000
```

which is not what I want of course.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Er. If `023.000` is not what you want, why did you tell `printf` to output a `0`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want 5 characters, 3 of which after the period. I've also tried "%05.3f" which prints correctly 23.000 but also prints 3.000 instead of 03.000

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to put the `0` *after* the `%`:

```
printf "%06.3f\n" 23.00
```

Notice that I also increased the minimum field width to 6, otherwise no padding will occur (3 decimal places, one dot, leaves just a single digit in front of the decimal point).

Answer (score 2):

If anything at all, the 0 would have to be on the right side of the percent sign. I don't have a linux system at work, but try `printf "%05.3f\n" 23.00`.